# If the limit of $f$ is less than the limit of $g$, then $f<g$ in some neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) := L$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) := M$ and $L < M$. 
I aim to prove that $\max\{f(x), g(x)\} = g(x)$ on some $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$.

So here is what I have so far:
Suppose $d$ is the distance between $M$ and $L$ (i.e. $M - L := d > 0$). Since the limits exist, there exist $\delta_f$ and $\delta_g$ such that $0 < |x - c| < \delta_f$ and $0 < |x - c| < \delta_g$ imply $|f(x) - L| < d/2$ [(1)] and $|g(x) - M| < d/2$ [(2)], respectively.

I also know that I can the minimum of $\delta_f$ and $\delta_g$, say $\delta$ such that $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ implies both (1) and (2). I have been using triangle inequalities to get somewhere but I have realized that I do not know which end statement I am trying to reach. One idea is that I want to show that  $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$? But I am not so sure if that says that  $\max\{f(x), g(x)\} = g(x)$ on some $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$.

Comment: To show $\max\{f(x), g(x)\} = g(x)$ on some nbd, it suffices to show $g(x) \ge f(x)$ on that nbd.

Comment: Alternatively, it's easy to show that if $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$, then $h(x)$ is non-zero on some neighborhood around $c$.

Comment: I know that. But I cannot get further that the statement $|g(x)| - |f(x)| < |M| - |L|$.

Comment: Why are you dividing $d$ into two parts? What is the geometric reason for that?

Comment: I am new to analysis and I have seen my professor doing that on several occasions. I am just trying all possible ways I can think of.

Comment: Note that you have shown $f(x) \in (L - d/2, L+d/2)$ and $g(x) \in (M-d/2, M+d/2)$, and this two interval does not intercept. Indeed, the latter interval is on the right side of the former one. What's the conclusion?

Comment: If that is true, then the conclusion is that $g(x) \geq f(x)$. Wow. I think I GOT IT. Because $d\2 < d$ the two intervals do not intercept.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$. From the given conditions, its clear that $\lim_{x \to c}h(x) = \alpha>0 \; \; (\alpha := M-L)$ which means that there exists some $\delta$ such that $\lvert h(x) -\alpha \rvert < \frac{\alpha}{2}$ whenever $\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta$

$\lvert h(x) -\alpha \rvert < \frac{\alpha}{2} \implies 0<\frac{\alpha}{2} < h(x) <\frac{3\alpha}{2}$

This shows that when $x$ is in $\delta$ neighborhood of $c$, $h(x)$ is positive and hence $g$ dominates $f$ in this neighborhood.

Comment: Who ever down voted: can you please explain the errors/mistakes my proof. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is of course correct. But it is better to follow the line of proof of the OP, since the OP has almost finished the proof. IMO your answer is not helpful to the OP.

Comment: sure! Thanks. I was just wondering if you downvoted because i did some mistake. I tried to prove it in a different way and i just got to know that its not worth my time as i m getting downvoted 

Comment: Well. The downvote is not from me.